# Problem installing Bluetooth Dongle on Raspberry Pi 3 running Windows 10 IOT Core

Tags: pi-3, bluetooth, windows-iot, usb-power

I recently bought the plugable Bluetooth USB adapter usb-bt4le and I want to use it with my RPi3. I have windows 10 core IoT installed on the RPi. I have disabled the on-board bluetooth and I wish to use the usb bluetooth for communicating with the RPi. I wish to know how to install the bluetooth drivers on the RPi. Their support site mentioned that windows installs the drivers by itself but it doesn’t seem to be doing that. I tried downloading the drivers from the website but that isn’t installing the drivers either. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Windows 10 Desktop OS Windows IoT doesn’t support a lot of Bluetooth or wireless devices, please check this link to know which devices are supported https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/hardwarecompatlist